# Galaxy Z Flip - show screen automatically when flipped open

Tags: samsung, lock-screens

Samsung says that the lock screen can be turned off with:

Go to Settings > Lock screen > Screen lock type > enter your passcode > None > Remove data.

I don't have the 'None' option though, please see:

[image]

So currently I need to press the button to show the lock screen, and then swipe it up to access the phone.. it's annoying. How do you make the lock screen go away completely?

Comment: A couple of years ago some users reported that None option was visible but greyed out. It was traced to a device administrator app. See if a device administrator app enforced this lock screen policy (doesn't make sense though). As a workaround, you can try an automation app wherein the action is to automatically swipe the lockscreen once display lights up.

Comment: thanks bud........................